# scala Enumeration retrieving enum by withName when Value has argument

Tags: scala, enumeration

Say i have enum like this:

```
  object Enm extends Enumeration {
        val ONE, TWO, THREE = Value
  }
```

and it's possible for me to get disired result by calling with name on it `Enm.withName("ONE")`, but if i have Value with argument, say:

```
object Enm extends Enumeration {
     val ONE = Value("1")
     val TWO = Value("2")
     val THREE = Value("3")
}
```

calling `Enm.withName("ONE")` i get back noting since it's now "1", "2" and so on.
Is it possible somehow to get val names but not the ones i put in Value?

Comment: why do you need that? i think perhaps the only way is to pattern match them.

Comment: `Enm.values.filter(_.toString.startsWith("1")).max` for now i use this construction but i suspect that there should be more formal approach.

Comment: why not use `Enm.withName("1")`?

Comment: because of input i've got. So in my case i use Value's argument to print the full name of enum ordinal and i have to find it using input which in my case is the ONE, TWO, THREE

Comment: but in fact you used "startsWith("1")", right? if you need to  match "ONE", "TWO", "THREE" literal, perhaps you'd use pattern matching.

Comment: i consider it as a temporary solution, if it's not possible i will back to something like `Value("ONE", "1")` and so on with some class that extends Val(string, string).

Answer (score 1):

**Hacky solution**

Maintain a `Map` of word string to Number string mapping

```
object Enm extends Enumeration {
     val ONE = Value("1")
     val TWO = Value("2")
     val THREE = Value("3")
     val map = Map ("ONE" -> "1", "TWO" -> "2", "THREE" -> "3")
}

//Usage
Enm.withName(Enm.map("ONE"))
```

You cannot override `withName` method as it is `final`. So write a custom withName method

```
 object Enm extends Enumeration {
     val ONE = Value("1")
     val TWO = Value("2")
     val THREE = Value("3")
     private val map = Map ("ONE" -> "1", "TWO" -> "2", "THREE" -> "3")
     def customWithName(str: String) = withName(map(str))
 }

 //Usage
 Enm.customWithName("ONE")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without changing the existing enum object?